# python merge and unmatched records also need to exists

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, merge

I have two files

input.csv

```
11/13/2020 07:41:09 TREE count1: id1 green001
11/13/2020 07:43:09 TREE count1: id1 black001
11/13/2020 07:45:09 TREE count1: id2 black001
11/13/2020 07:45:09 PLAN count1: id3 green002
11/13/2020 07:45:09 PLAN count1: id4 green004
```

lookup.csv

```
ID,item,message
id1,item1,message 1
id2,item2,message 2
id3,item3,message 3
```

I am trying to merge both files and expected below output
Expected output:

```
Time,Type,counts,id,item,message,colour
11/13/2020 07:41:09,TREE,count1,id1,item1,message 1,green001
11/13/2020 07:43:09,TREE,count1,id1,item1,message 1,black001
11/13/2020 07:45:09,TREE,count1,id2,item2,message 2,black001
11/13/2020 07:45:09,PLAN,count1,id3,item3,message 3,green002
11/13/2020 07:45:19,PLAN,count1,id4,     ,         ,green004
```

I am able to achieve that able to merge when ID value present in lookup file.
Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# read input and remove spurious : at end of count
input = pd.read_csv("input.csv", sep=' ',
         names=["date","time", "tree","count","ID", "info"])
input["count"] = input["count"].apply(lambda s:s[:-1])

# read lookup and merge
lookup = pd.read_csv("lookup.csv")
merged = input.merge(lookup, on="ID")

# collapse time and date to single column
merged["time"] = merged["date"] + " " + merged["time"]
del merged["date"]

# output
print(merged)
merged.to_csv("testme.csv", index=False)
```

Code is working fine if all ID values in input.csv exists in lookup.csv file, but fails when ID value not exists in lookup.csv file

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 'how' input of merge from 'inner' to 'left' or 'outer'. Default is 'inner' which will only result in a merge where ID is in both DataFrames. You can also set the indicator flag that will tell you which records are in each DataFrame.

```py
merged = input.merge(lookup, on="ID", how='left')

merged = input.merge(lookup, on="ID", how='outer', indicator=True)
```